# Remove a specific object from a collection on condition

Tags: laravel

I have a collection of objects which are rows in a DB.

[image]

In my controller i call all `fileuploads` and all `userfileuploads`:

```
$allFileuploads = Fileupload::all();
$existingFileuploads = UserFileupload::where('userid', $user->id)->get();
```

Fileupload model and UserFileupload model don't have the same properties.

How to get fileuploads from `$allFileuploads` collection where `id` == `fileupload_id` from `$existingFileuploads` collection?

#### update

I have tried this now and i get an empty collection:

```
$allFileuploads = Fileupload::get();
$existingFileuploads = UserFileupload::where('userid', $user->id)->get();
$existingIds = $existingFileuploads->pluck('id')->toArray();

$selectedFiles = $allFileuploads->filter(function ($file) use ($existingIds) {
    return in_array($file->id, $existingIds);
});

dd($selectedFiles);
```

#### update

It works with the accepted answer...I used wrong name to get the fileupload_id

Comment: so to be clear, I'm not trying to get userFileuploads but the uploadfields for html view from my Fileuploads table

Comment: I have tried 'diff' and 'contains' but i couldn't make it to work. i need something like if (fileupload->id == userFileupload->fileupload_id) drop that object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this approch.

```
$allFileuploads = Fileupload::get();
$existingFileuploads = UserFileupload::where('userid', $user->id)->get();
$existingIds = $existingFileuploads->pluck('id')->toArray();
$selectedFiles = $allFileuploads->filter(function ($file) use ($existingIds) {
    return in_array($file->id, $existingIds);
});
```

First you [plucks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) ids from `existingFileuploads` and then you [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter) them from `$allFileuploads`

Comment: i get this error `Array to string conversion` because  `$existingIds` is an array

Comment: OK i have figured it out. You must put toArray() at the end of this line: `$existingIds = $existingFileuploads->pluck('id')->toArray();` then it works...thank you

Comment: Oh I just realized....I need the opposite! Now I get the ones user has selected...but I need the ones that are not selected! How to get them now?

Comment: just put `!` in front of `in_array($file->id, $existingIds);`

Comment: I updated the answer with `->toArray()`. Thanks for noticing it and glad you found this helpful :)